# How to remove first br tag only if occurs before the text in paragraph?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have paragraphs with the collection of text and `<br>` tags. I want to remove the very first `<br>` tag, if it occurs before the text in any paragraph.

Like this:

```
<p>
  <br>
  Lorem Ipsum is dummy text.
</p>
```

I want like this:

```
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is dummy text.
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the first `childNode` is a `<br>` and delete/hide like below:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var first = this.childNodes[0];
    while((!first.tagName && $.trim(first.textContent) == '') || (first.tagName && first.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'br')) {
        this.removeChild(first);
        first = (this.childNodes && this.childNodes.length > 0) ? this.childNodes[0] : null;
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/makZ7/1/

**Updated demo (removes any leading empty text node(s) as well):** http://jsfiddle.net/WQ9f3/5/

Input:

```
<p><br/>Hello<br/>World</p>
<p><br/>Hello<br/>World<br/>Hey!</p>
```

Output:

```
<p>Hello<br/>World</p>
<p>Hello<br/>World<br/>Hey!</p>
```

Comment: This will fail and throw a TypeError if the first `childNode` is a `textNode` which doesn't have `tagName` property. `Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Ahh, in the OP's input the first childNode is actually an empty text node. Can probably tweak the solution to discard any empty text nodes before the first `<br>` if any.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$("p br:first-child").filter(function () {
    var prev = this.previousSibling;
    return prev == null || $.trim(prev.nodeValue) == ''
}).remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WQ9f3/)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use regular expression to remove the `<br/>` tag.

**[JsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/29FGu/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var exp = /^\s*?(<br(\/>|>))/gi;
    $('p').each(function (idx, elm) {
        elm = $(elm);
        elm.html(elm.html().replace(exp, ''));
    });
});
```

The code checks the inner html of each `p` tag, ignoring any spaces, replaces the `<br>` or `<br/>` tag at the start of the text with an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MDpbf/)**

```
$("p br:first-child").remove();
```

Comment: p>br:first-child{display:none;} by doing this i can remove first br but in condition when: 

<p>
  there is text here too than...
  <br>
  Lorem Ipsum is dummy text.
</p>

because in this case i don't have to remove br tag